# Is class of threshold functions Agnostic PAC Learnable?

Tags: machine-learning, learning-theory

In "Understanding Machine Learning, From Theory to Algorithms" by Shalev and Ben-David, on page 44 example 6.1, it is proved that the class of threshold functions are PAC learnable.
on the other hand, The Fundamental Theory of Statistical Learning States that A-PAC learnable is equivalent to PAC learnable.

So can we say that class of threshold functions is also A-PAC learnable?

My second question is what is the difference between the two?

Comment: It seems like you have answered your own question.  I'm not sure what kind of answer you are expecting.  If you understand the proof of the equivalence, you should be able to convince yourself whether it is true.  If you don't, perhaps it would be more useful to ask a question about some specific aspect you don't understand?

Comment: *Fundamental Theory of Statistical **Inference***? (I think the `States` should *not* start with a capital letter.)